# I can't find my husband or my follower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I married Marcelo and I told him to move to Breezehome. I keep going there but he's not there. I've gone to the temple of Mara and to the Bee and Bard in Riften. I don't know where he is.  Where's my husband?

Also I can't find Cicero I spared him and lied to Astrid so he'd be my follower but I don't know where he is.

Comment: Have you tried "waiting" in each location for your husband? And do yiu know where Cicero waits if you dismiss him? Try checking there.

Comment: Additionally, are you on PC or console?

Comment: Cicero won't appear as a follower until the DB quest is sufficiently advanced. Has he thus far announced his attention to serve you?

Comment: I suspect a tryst...

Comment: 1. Wait 2. Complete Dark Brotherhood Questline.